# Using same FK in mutliple tables.

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
create table TRASchema.Member (
TRAnum int IDENTITY not null, 
name varchar(30) not null, 
status int not null, 
DOB date not null, 
constraint PK_TRAnum primary key (TRAnum)
)

create table RaceSchema.RaceEntry

(bibNumber int IDENTITY not null, 
AgeCode nchar(2) not null, 
ClubID int not null,
TRAnum int not null, 
position int not null, 
RaceID int not null, 
constraint PK_bibNumber primary key (bibNumber),
constraint FK_AgeCode foreign key (AgeCode) references 
TRASchema.AgeCatagoryClass(AgeCode),
constraint FK_ClubID foreign key (ClubID) references TRASchema.Club(ClubID),
)
```

Now I would like to be able to use the same TRAnum on my Race Entry system but as a FK. When I try to do this I would add this constraint to the RaceEntry Table

```
constraint FK_TRAnum foreign key (TRAnum) references 
TRASchema.Member(TRAnum)
```

When I do this I am informed that the attribute TRAnum already exists elsewhere in my DB which is correct it does and I want to use it again onthis table as a FK?

Any direction on where I am going wrong would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use the same constraint name FK_TRAnum.  You can have multiple tables all with an FK that reference the same table, but each constraint must have a unique name.